# pandas standard error calculation issue

Tags: python, pandas

I’m having some problems using pandas to get the right standard error value for some data. Here is how to reproduce the problem.

```
import pandas as pd

# get the data
data = {'subject_number':[1,7,8,9,10,13],
       'condition_number':[1,2,1,1,1,2],
       'pre-score':[26.4495, 58.9345, 73.345, 41.081, 36.016, 8.4415],
       'post-score':[49.71, 52.178, 44.0825, 52.711, 13.506, 39.7675]}

dataset = pd.DataFrame(data)

# get means
means = dataset.groupby('condition_number').mean()
means.drop('subject_number', axis=1)

# get stdevs
stdevs = dataset.groupby('condition_number').std()
stdevs.drop('subject_number', axis=1)

# get standard errors
sems = dataset.groupby('condition_number').sem()
sems.drop('subject_number', axis=1)
```

This is fine, and it all works, however I tested this in excel and found a discrepancy. The means and standard devs are fine, but the sem calculates the uncorrected (std / sqrt(n)) value, instead of the corrected value for sample (std / sqrt(n-1)). Here is the output in excel:

[image]

I think the problem might be something to do with the unequal n per condition? As we see in the dataset, the n for condition 1 is 4, while condition 2 n=2. [sorry, the dictionary assignment messed with the order of the pandas df columns...]

Can someone help to explain what is going on here?

Comment: thanks, that seems to do the job. it's strange that we have to have such specific code to reach this solution though because calculating standard error is pretty common practice. surprised that there isn't a pandas function to achieve this.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting standard error calculations. Standard error of the mean is the standard deviation of all sample means. Normally, you would calculate that by dividing population standard deviation over n. Since you don't have access to population standard deviation, you use sample standard deviation. You don't use *sample standard deviation of the sample means*.

Comment: @ayhan I'm not trying to calculate SE based on the sample means, but based on the data itself. I just created the means table for reference. the SE calculation would be based off of the data in the main table in range A1:D7 of the image. But after reading your comment I see I've made a mistake! It should simply be sample stdev/sqrt(n). Not sample stdev/sqrt(n-1).

Should I delete the question since it's pretty useless to do this? Sorry I'm relatively new to SO!

Comment: Yes you are right. So either you use `result.sem()`  which by default uses the sample standard deviation or `result.sem(ddof=0)` which uses the population standard deviation. No need to delete the question it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your function with

```
In [846]: (dataset.groupby('condition_number')
                  .agg(lambda x: x.std()/x.count().add(-1).pow(0.5)))
Out[846]:
                  post-score  pre-score  subject_number
condition_number
1                  10.405407  11.743628        2.357023
2                   8.775549  35.703943        4.242641
```